# I have assigned an object during ionViewDidLoad, but the object still empty

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

I am new to Ionic, I have this problem when trying to pass navParams to other pages. I want to pass the **team object** from **TeamHomePage** to **TeamDetailPage**. but I always got the **null**. I have check in the ionViewDidLoad, and console it to make sure the team object is assigned, and try to pass a testing object (successfully). Anyone has any idea when is the object of the team went?

```
<ion-tabs>
  <ion-tab tabTitle="Team" [root]='teamDetailTab' [rootParams]='testing' tabIcon="basketball"></ion-tab>
  <ion-tab tabTitle="Standings" [root]='standingsTab' [rootParams]='team' tabIcon="podium"></ion-tab>
</ion-tabs>
```

TeamHomePage.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController, NavParams } from 'ionic-angular';
import { TeamDetailPage } from '../team-detail/team-detail';
import { StandingsPage } from '../standings/standings';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-team-home',
  templateUrl: 'team-home.html',
})
export class TeamHomePage {
  public team: any = {}
  public teamDetailTab = TeamDetailPage
  public standingsTab = StandingsPage
  public testing: any = {id:1, content: 'testing'}

  constructor(
    public navCtrl: NavController,
    public navParams: NavParams) {}

  ionViewDidLoad() {
    this.team = this.navParams.data
    console.log('TeamHomePage navParams.data:')
    console.log(this.navParams.data)
    console.log('TeamHomePage this.team:')
    console.log(this.team)
  }

  goHome() {
    this.navCtrl.popToRoot()
  }

}
```

TeamDetailPage.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController, NavParams } from 'ionic-angular';
import { EliteApi } from '../../providers/elite-api/elite-api';
import { GamePage } from '../game/game';

import * as _ from 'lodash'


@Component({
  selector: 'page-team-detail',
  templateUrl: 'team-detail.html',
})
export class TeamDetailPage {
  public team: any = {}
  public games: any[]
  private tourneyData: any

  constructor(
    public navCtrl: NavController,
    public navParams: NavParams,
    private eliteApi: EliteApi
   ) {}

  ionViewDidLoad() {
    this.team = this.navParams.data
    this.tourneyData = this.eliteApi.getCurrentTourney()
    this.games = _.chain(this.tourneyData.games)
                  .filter(g => g.team1Id === this.team.id || g.team2Id === this.team.id)
                  .map(g => {
                    let isTeam1 = (g.teamId === this.team.id)
                    let opponentName = isTeam1 ? g.team2: g.team1
                    let scoreDisplay = this.getScoreDisplay(isTeam1, g.team1Score, g.team2Score)
                    return {
                      gameId: g.id,
                      opponent: opponentName,
                      time: Date.parse(g.time),
                      location: g.location,
                      locationUrl: g.locationUrl,
                      scoreDisplay: scoreDisplay,
                      homeAway: (isTeam1 ? "vs.": "at")
                    }
                  })
                  .value()
                  console.log('TeamDetail team:')
                  console.log(this.navParams.data)
                  console.log('TeamDetail: tourneyData')
                  console.log(this.tourneyData)
                  console.log('TeamDetail touerneyData.games:')
                  console.log(this.tourneyData.games)
  }

  getScoreDisplay(isTeam1, team1Score, team2Score) {
    if (team1Score && team2Score) {
      var teamScore = (isTeam1 ? team1Score : team2Score)
      var opponentScore = (isTeam1 ? team2Score : team1Score)
      var winIndicator = teamScore > opponentScore ? 'W: ' : 'L: '
      return winIndicator + teamScore + '-' + opponentScore
    }else {
      return ''
    }
  }
```

Empty Team Object showing in console chrome

[image]

Comment: I kinda solved the problem by putting it in the constructor, hmm weird, but the tutorial has shown me to put in ionViewDidLoad. Can you guys teach me how this is happening?